# Как хранить и как редактировать данные на сайте без sql?

Tags: javascript, json

Ребят, подскажите пожалуйста.
Я делаю небольшой проект для собственных нужд,
мне надо хранить данные локально, обращаться к ним и редактировать.
Хочу решить вопрос без использования локального сервера.
Нагуглил что можно через json, но как не понял, помогите пожалуйста)

Comment: localStorage  ... JSON.stringify()   .........JSON.parse()

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: IndexedDB хранит локально. Но в целом да, не ясно. Что значит "без использования сервера"?

Comment: @hlearn ещё websql забыли... как по мне - он лучше) хотя в итоге и там и там придётся писать... правда у них размер ограничен ещё